# Copying data from a temp table to another table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

after 30 minutes of searching on stackoverflow, i was unsuccessful in finding an answer to my problem.

I have a form that uses a table (lets call this table1) as the record source. This form is also a subform that has parent and child links to certain fields. The subform also is used to insert multiple records at once.

I have a button coded that saves the records to table1.

What i want to do is move the saved data from table1 to say table2 and then delete the contents of table1.

Put it this way, i am using table1 as a temp table for storage when importing data, table2 will keep all the records saved from table1.

Does this make any sense?

Thank you

```
Private Sub Command8_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command8_Click
'' Adds values to tbl and clears the form for next submission

DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acRecordsMenu, acSaveRecord, , acMenuVer70
Me.CounterId.Value = Null
Me.CounterDate.Value = Null
Me.QBLID.Value = Null
Me.QBLDate.Value = Null
Me.TPICID.Value = Null
Me.TPICDate.Value = Null
Me.Last.Form.Requery




Exit_Command8_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_Command8_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_Command8_Click







End Sub
```

Comment: All you need is two queries, one to add to the main table and one to delete from temp. You can pass the record id as parameter to both queries.

Comment: @KostasK. I forgot to mention Table 2 will also be receiving identical information from another table (lets call this table 3) will there be issues with the record id being identical?